# Play Framework's Embedded JS router giving me 404

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.6

I'm trying to use Play! 2.6 Framework's embedded router for my Javascript routes as indicated in their [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJavascriptRouting). I'm using the Scala version and attempting to submit a form through AJAX/jQuery.

I've plunked this into my main.scala.html template which decorates every returned script:

```
@helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
        routes.javascript.DashboardController.postNewProject,
        routes.javascript.DashboardController.getSliderResponse
    )
```

And here's the controller with those methods:

```
@Singleton
class DashboardController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

     def postNewProject() = Action{ ... }

     def getSliderResponse(str:String)= Action { ... }
}
```

and I've wired those up in the `Routes.conf` as follows

```
POST    /dashboard/projects    controllers.DashboardController.postNewProject
GET     /dashboard/projects/sliderSubmitResponse/:response   controllers.DashboardController.getSliderResponse(response: String)
```

But when I load this via an AJAX call - my console is telling me I'm getting a 404 error. Here's the AJAX:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.sliderForms', function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var content = $('#projectTitleInputBox').val();
    var content2 = $('#initNoteBox').val();
    window.alert("Made it here at least" + content + ' ' + content2);

    jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.postNewProject().ajax({
        success: loadDoc('jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.getSliderResponse("newProjSuccess")', 'createNewProjectDiv'),
        fail: loadDoc('jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.getSliderResponse("newProjFail")', 'createNewProjectDiv')
    })

});
```

And I'm getting a 404 error, as it's attempting to retrieve this URL:

```
http://localhost:9000/dashboard/jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.getSliderResponse("newProjSuccess")

http://localhost:9000/dashboard/jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.getSliderResponse("newProjFail")
```

So I think I have the routing incorrect, but not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, you can't use the reverse routing in an AJAX request.
I need to change this:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.postNewProject().ajax({
        success: loadDoc('jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.getSliderResponse("newProjSuccess")', 'createNewProjectDiv'),
        fail: loadDoc('jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.getSliderResponse("newProjFail")', 'createNewProjectDiv')
    })
```

to

```
jsRoutes.controllers.DashboardController.postNewProject().ajax({
        success: loadDoc('/url/ofMethod/asAppears/inMy/conf.Routes', 'createNewProjectDiv'),
        fail: loadDoc('/url/ofMethod/asAppears/inMy/conf.Routes', 'createNewProjectDiv')
    })
```